# Remove time from pandas dataframe datetime64[ns] index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to merge two pandas dataframes, and to do this I want to make it so that they both have the same index. The problem is, one df has an index of datatype `object` which just includes the date while the other df has an index of datatype `datetime64[ns]` which includes the date and time. Is there a way to make these both the same data type so that I can merge the two dataframes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert both date types into a pandas datetime format and convert them with having just dates.

```
df['date_only'] = df['dates'].dt.date
```

You could convert a date and time format to just date as below

```
import pandas as pd
date_n_time='2015-01-08 22:44:09' 
date=pd.to_datetime(date_n_time).date()
```

**make your index as a column using**

```
df.reset_index()
```

set it back to index using

```
df.set_index()
```

Comment: The dates are in the index, not in a column of the dataframe. Do you have a way to change the index?

Comment: @shroomz df.reset_index() will make your index as a column